# getting a distinct value from db through cake-php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Hi i want to get distinct values from a particular column from cakephp.

This is what i have tried:-

```
 $new_data =$this->Event->findAll(null, 'DISTINCT events.source');

Event- is the name of my model.
events- is my table name in db.
Source:- is the column name from which i want to fetch values.
```

I dnt knw what is wrong in the query, can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Event->find('all', array('group' => 'Event.source'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`findAll` is not actually a cakephp method. What you want to do is:

```
$this->Event->find('all', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT Event.source'));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-all

Comment: Thanks but i am getting output as [object Object], instead of url

Comment: And also values arent distinct

Comment: What do you mean by [object Object]? That sounds like javascript.

Comment: my output should be some url, but instead i am getting  [object Object] in my jquery. I am fetching the db result through ajax

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Did you inspect the request? In chrome you can right click and select "Inspect Element". Under the network tab you can see what requests are being made. Inspect your request and tell me what it says.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Event->find('all', array('group' => 'Event.source'));
```